Unexpected error, Unknown Syntax encountered when using Pycharm
I am using Python's docarray package to create a vector database, but have encountered an error saying "Unknown syntax" when entering the following line of code from the docarray documentation: .filter(filter_query={'price': {'$lte': 3}})  # post-filtering. I have tried to find a solution using Google search and Stack Over Flow, but have been unable to find a solution.
Has anyone encountered this error before? If yes, can you give me advice me about how to resolve this error?
I have tried to find a solution using Reddit, Google, Stack Over Flow and the Docarray's GitHub page, but have been unable to find a solution.
